# SCCM 2007 move computers between collections

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi, sccm, sccm-2007

I have no code to provide for this because I am not familiar with SCCM 2007. I am hoping that someone maybe can help me with the whole process.
What I am trying to achieve is to get computers which are installed with windows 7 32-bit, they have their own collection and move them to the collection for windows 7 64-bit.
I prefer to do this with a script cause we´re talking about approx 2000 clients.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use dynamically collection for the "windows 7 64- bit" Clients. If all Clients are imported via the dynamically query you can copy paste all clients in a your new direct collection.

A query may look like this 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/3591397c-157e-40ce-b3f4-9d304efa21ac/sccm-querycollection-windows-7-x64?forum=configmgrgeneral